# Don't see jenkins in web browser

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, server

I have virtual server, where is installed Ubuntu and jdk, then I installed jenkins according to tutorial https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu. When I run jenkins everything is ok.

```
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:54 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:54 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.9
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:56 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /home/student/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:59 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 1 ms
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 52312
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:54 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:54 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.9
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:56 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /home/student/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:57 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 13, 2015 1:41:59 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 1 ms
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 52312
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Dec 13, 2015 1:42:00 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

But, when I want see jenkins in browser like localhost:8080 (I tried other ports too), this page doesn't load. 
Any sugesstions?

Comment: You need to use name(or IP address) of the machine running jenkins instead of "localhost".

Comment: Yes, I used. Lohalhost is example.